# change foreground color of textblock inside stackpanel using c# in windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Here is my xaml

```
 <ListBox   Margin="3,60,1,10" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Row="1" Name="lstAnnouncement" Tap="lstAnnouncement_Tap" Width="476" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalMargin">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>

                <StackPanel   Name="thispanel"  Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="120" Width="478" >

                    <StackPanel.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Text-ALU.png" Stretch="Fill" />
                        <!--<SolidColorBrush  Color="{Binding Path=background}"/>-->
                    </StackPanel.Background>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
                            <!--<toolkit:MenuItem Header="Remove " Click="MenuItem_Click"/>-->
                        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="30" Margin="0,0,0,2" Background="#FF0195D5" Height="118">
                        <!--<Grid.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Text-ALU.png" Stretch="Fill" />
                        </Grid.Background>-->
                        <TextBlock  x:Name="txtDate" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=announcementDate}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="-43.169,44.001,-43.831,0" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" TextAlignment="Center" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="117">
                            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform Rotation="-90"/>
                            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="5" Height="120"/>
                    <StackPanel   Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="432" Height="114">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtTitle" Height="27" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=announcementTitle}"   FontSize="18.667" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="432" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="432" Height="27">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtBy" FontWeight="Bold" Height="27" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=announcementBy}"  FontSize="18.667" Width="399"/>
                            <Image x:Name="imgArrow" Width="25" Source="Images/Go-In-Arrow.png" Height="25" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="433" Height="60">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtDesc" FontWeight="Bold" Height="58" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=announcementShortDescription}" FontSize="18.667" Width="371"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtID" Height="56" Text="{Binding Path=announcementID}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" FontSize="18.667" Width="8" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            <Image x:Name="imgType" Width="35" Source="{Binding Path=announcementTypeImage}" Height="40" Margin="27,20,0,0" d:LayoutOverrides="Height"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

i want to change foreground color of textblocxk with x:name txtDesc in code behind using c#

i am trying

```
txtDesc.Foreground = Brushes.White;
```

but it not recognizing it so how to achieve it? also is there any other way to change foreground  colour using binding

Comment: How are you calling the C# code that is supposed to change the `TextBlock` color?

Comment: txtDesc.Foreground = Brushes.White;  but it says txtdesc is not in curretn context @madd0

Comment: Well, the reason the C# won't compile is because the TextBlock is in a data template, so it cannot be referenced by name from the page's code behind, since there will most likely be several instances of it. To help you further, you'd have to better describe what you are trying to achieve and how.

Comment: i am trying to achieve to change txtdesc foreground color to blue if item is read=1 and change foreground color to black if itemread=0 @madd0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, the reason that your code is not compiling is because your `TextBlock` is part of a `DataTemplate` of a `ListBox` and not on object on the page itself. You'd therefore expect several instances to exist; how would can you identify them all with only one identifier?

You later mentioned in the comments that what you want to do is change the colour of the `TextBlock` in each list item according to the value of a property of the item. There are several ways to do it.

You could use Blend behaviours:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding announcementShortDescription}" >
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Value="1" Binding="{Binding itemread}">
                    <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Foreground">
                        <Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue"/>
                        </Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                    </Core:ChangePropertyAction>
                </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

My preferred choice, though, would be to use a value converter. Something like:

```
class ItemReadToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        int val = (int)value;

        return val == 0 ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And in the XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="list">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <local:ItemReadToColorConverter x:Key="conv" />
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding itemread, Converter={StaticResource conv}}" Text="{Binding announcementShortDescription}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

Xaml:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtDesc" FontWeight="Bold" Height="58" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Text="{Binding Path=announcementShortDescription}" FontSize="18.667" Width="371" Foreground="Yellow"/>
```

CS:

```
txtDesc.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
```

Comment: it gives error txtDesc does not exist in the current context @A B

Comment: i want to change it form c# @a b

Comment: i think you should go for binding or you can do it in xaml easily. as your view is quite complex.